# Python stdout redirection (special)

Tags: python, python-2.7, shell, stdout

I'm currently building a shell in python.
The shell can execute python files, but I also need to add the option to use PIPEs (for example '|' means that the output of the first command will be the input of the second command).

In order to do so, I need to have the option to take what the first command was going to print (notice that the command might not be a system command but a python file that has the line

```
print 'some information'
```

I need to pass it on to a variable in the shell.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect `sys.stdout` to an in-memory [`BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) or [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.StringIO) file-like object:

```
import sys
from io import BytesIO

buf = BytesIO()
sys.stdout = buf

# Capture some output to the buffer
print 'some information'
print 'more information'

# Restore original stdout
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__

# Display buffer contents
print 'buffer contains:', repr(buf.getvalue())
buf.close()
```

**output**

```
buffer contains: 'some information\nmore information\n'
```

Comment: I tried this. Instead of using 'print' I tried os.system('dir'). It still printed to the screen, though it got 0 into the buf. so it took this response, but didn't prevent the printing inside... :(

Comment: @OphirBack That's because `os.system` runs in a subshell that inherits the shell's original `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` handles, so it's unaffected by the redirection that my code performs. But you shouldn't be using `os.system` except for very simple stuff. Take a look at the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module, which gives you control over the input and output of commands.

Comment: @OphirBack Also, seriously consider using Python 3. There's not much point developing new things in Python 2, since it will not be supported after 2020.

Comment: I wasn't sure about the subprocess thing so thanks a lot!